# how to write javascript to handle checkbox and send data to variable?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

using MVC and bootstrap, there is a boolean true/false checkbox.  but the SQL database must have a text only field.

```
   input type =  checkbox; name = xactive" onclick="setvalue"
<script> function(setvalue)
if(checkbotive == checked) {model => model.PType1 = "Yes";}
else {model => model.PType1 = "No";
</script>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `document.Form1.checkbox2.checked == true`? Because `checkbox2` probably is undefined.

Comment: FYI you can pass an argument to your functions, like `function Applealert(checkbox)` and change the onclick with `Applealert(this)`, then in the Applealert function you will be able to do `checkbox.checked == true`

Answer (score 1):

You should always refer to IDs in your HTML, because they are per definition unique. You get a specific HTML-Tag/Item per ID with `document.getElementById()`. You could also refer to your checkboxes with `document.getElementByName()`. The thing is that `document.getElementByName()` will return an Array, because Names **are not** unique

Just rewrite your whole *html* like that:

```
<input id="checkbox1"
    type="checkbox"
    name="checkbox1"
    onclick="Applealert()" />Apple
<br />
<input id="checkbox2"
    type="checkbox"
    name="checkbox2"
    onclick="Orangealert()" />Orange     

<script>
    function Applealert()
    {
        if(document.getElementById("checkbox1").checked == true)
        {
            alert("You have clicked on Apple.");
        }
    }
    function Orangealert()
    {
        if(document.getElementById("checkbox2").checked == true)
        {
            alert("You have clicked on Orange.");
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: so i don't understand your question, i believe. i can stop at every point with my debugger

Comment: i don't know. i always debug with _Chrome Developer Tools_

Comment: I just updated the answer above with code to try to modify the original Model parameter.  click the checkbox and it should update the variable then be able to create a new record but when created there is no data even when the model.startdate is directly set to a string value?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fiddle that I think answers your question.

You can get elements on the page by their ID.  That should help you with your alerts.

http://jsfiddle.net/6dtudsad/

```
function Applealert()
{
    if(document.getElementById('checkbox1').checked)
    {
        alert("You have clicked on Apple.");
    }
}

function Orangealert()
{
    if(document.getElementById('checkbox2').checked)
    {
        alert("You have clicked on Orange.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shortened version:

```
<input id="checkbox1"
    type="checkbox"
    name="checkbox1"
    onclick="Applealert(this)" />Apple
<br />
<input id="checkbox2"
    type="checkbox"
    name="checkbox2"
    onclick="Orangealert(this)" />Orange     

<script>
    function Applealert(checkbox)
    {
        if(checkbox.checked == true)
        {
            alert("You have clicked on Apple.");
        }
    }
    function Orangealert(checkbox)
    {
        if(checkbox.checked == true)
        {
            alert("You have clicked on Orange.");
        }
    }

</script>
```